# Visual Studio 2010 and Web Deployment Projects (wdproj 2008)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, web-deployment-project

I have several wdprojects (web deployment 2008) in vs2008 solutions.
When I installed vs2010 RC none of my wdprojects will open.

What can I do to make it work?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Visual Studio 2010 Web Deployment Projects RTW is available here: [Visual Studio 2010 Web Deployment Projects RTW](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=89F2C4F5-5D3A-49B6-BCAD-F776C6EDFA63&displaylang=en)

**Update:**

As per [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11229582/will-web-deployment-projects-still-be-available-in-visual-studio-2012), Visual Studio 2012 does not have Web Deployment Projects.

But it's ok: [Visual Studio 2012 Web Deployment Projects are Dead – Long Live Publishing Profiles](http://www.diaryofaninja.com/blog/2012/08/26/visual-studio-2012-web-deployment-projects-are-dead-ndash-long-live-publishing-profiles)

Comment: Update: 10.0.30319.5 "RTW" (whatever that is) is available here, you I assume you shouldn't use the Beta anymore: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=89F2C4F5-5D3A-49B6-BCAD-F776C6EDFA63&displaylang=en

Comment: Just double checked and the link looks fine

Answer (score 1):

According to [this post](http://forums.asp.net/p/1515646/3720014.aspx) on the ASP.NET forum they will actually provide support for it some time after the release of Visual Studio 2010. But I can confirm that it is not supported out of the box in the Visual Studio 2010 RTM.

Answer (score 0):

Note there could also be some conflicts/warnings or errors when migrating.
Something like: 
"Unrecognized attribute 'targetFramework'. Note that attribute names are case-sensitive"

Here is an article which explains how to fix that:
http://extremedev.blogspot.com/2011/10/migrating-wdproj-from-vs-2008-to-vs.html

Answer (score -1):

VS 2010 convertor will convert the project as required when you try opening it in VS2010.

Comment: no it doesn't convert my wdproj projects. at leat not in the Release candidate. you think it does so in the RTM?