# How do I install Web deployment tool for VS 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, microsoft-web-deploy

I am opening a solution in Visual Studio 2010 and it's complaining about a wdproj file and says it can't open that project. I see that there is a web deployment tool to install for 2008 but i don't see the equivalent for 2010.

[I see this question which](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2622415/visual-studio-2010-and-web-deployment-projects-wdproj-2008), apparently says it has a link to a download but the download goes to a page that just says "We are sorry, the page you requested . . .'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you can download the Visual Studio® 2010 Web Deployment Projects - RTW here:  http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=24509