# Will Web Deployment Projects still be available in Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: visual-studio, setup-project, web-deployment-project, visual-studio-2012

It looks like Visual Studio 2012 will not include Visual Studio Setup and Deployment Projects according to [MSDN](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/buckh/archive/2011/03/17/visual-studio-setup-projects-vdproj-will-not-ship-with-future-versions-of-vs.aspx), so I'm currently learning [WiX](http://wix.codeplex.com/).

Will this loss of functionality extend to Web Deployment Projects?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

### Web Deployment Projects will NOT be available in VS2012.

Instead we will focus on bringing first class publishing support for Website projects. You can read more details at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2012/08/06/plans-regarding-website-projects-and-web-deployment-projects.aspx. In a nutshell, you will have all the same features that WDP has, but a lot more as well. Also another good thing about this is that we will have one experience for both Web App Project as well as Website Project. So when we make enhancements both project systems get it.

If you had any customizations in your WDP, you should be able to copy/paste those into the new web publish profiles (they are MSBuild as well). Take a look at the blog above and please do let me know if you have any concerns.

Comment: Funnily enough, I found this out myself just last week, but hadn't gotten around to updating the question here yet.  Thanks for the response.

Comment: Considering the volatility of MS deployment tools, I'm glad we decided to roll our own.  I've learned to lean on MSBuild and CI, and treat Visual Studio features as passing fads.

Comment: Here's a good post that describes the path forward: http://www.diaryofaninja.com/blog/2012/08/26/visual-studio-2012-web-deployment-projects-are-dead-ndash-long-live-publishing-profiles

Comment: Very bad decision imho. I know hundreds of developers who will skip vs2012. See also: http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/3041773-bring-back-the-basic-setup-and-deployment-project-  for more complaints

Comment: @pam that uservoice entry relates to setup and deployment projects.  Setup and deployment projects are totally different from Web Deployment Projects. For web scenarios publish profiles should cover the majority of WDP scenarios. Is there something that you are blocked on regarding Web?

Comment: I know, I was referring to winform deployment projects. I mainly work with winform applications. I was very upset having to get rid of the VS2012 version because of these issues. And so thousands people like me. You can't disrupt existing projects (and all the existing efforts in correct deployment) like this.

Comment: @pam I understand and I can relate to your feelings, but the link you are pointing to is totally unrelated to this question.

Comment: > totally unrelated   If that comforts you... that's explains much. (Apart that the decisions are obviously related... But continue hiding after some formal exception. It's good to be "right". I certainly never expected to obtain anything. I can continue use the 2010, no problem)

Comment: Sorry, not trying to be right. The decisions were not related, I was the one who made the call on WDP. In any case, I don't want you to get the impression that I'm arguing with you. Just trying to be as transparent as I can. Regarding WDP as I've said before if you are blocked without it please let me know. I will work with you directly to understand your issues and to see if there is something that needs to be done.

Answer (score 2):

I'm note sure if the links from user1069816 are relevant.

Visual Studio 2012 has an unsure inclusion of Web Deployment projects, but you can do something about it.

Vote for their inclusion: http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2639368-add-web-deployment-projects-to-vs11

Comment: IIRC Web Deployment Projects in VS2010 were a separate download and install add-on, so I'm OK with that in VS2012.  Just want to make sure the option is available.  It would be nice to see them included in the standard build though, so that definitely gets my votes.

Comment: A blog post about the subject:  http://sedodream.com/2012/08/06/PlansRegardingWebsiteProjectsAndWebDeploymentProjects.aspx

Comment: I think you should edit *unsure inclusion* to *definite exclusion*

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Web Deployment Projects will still exist in Visual Studio 2012 according to:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd394698(v=vs.110)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd394698%28v=vs.110%29)

and

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aspnetue/archive/2012/06/12/visual-studio-2012-rc-deployment-documentation-published.aspx

Comment: This is NOT accurate they will not be available, see my answer below, and these links have nothing to do with Web Deployment Projects.

Comment: I'll keep my upvote because at the time @user1069816 responded it was not clear. However, I've changed the answer.