# Visual Studio 2012 and Web Deployment Projects (wdproj)

Tags: visual-studio-2012, web-deployment-project

Can't seem to find any clear info on this. When I open my Visual Studio 2010 SP1 solution in Visual Studio 2012, it reports that wdproj is incompatible. What's the 2012 alternative to wdproj?

Comment: Same problem here. Hoping someone has more info about this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It looks like WDP (Web Deployment Projects, *.wdproj) is not going to be supported in VS 2012, someone has already answered the question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12061065/922169

... and here is the blog referenced in the answer: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2012/08/06/plans-regarding-website-projects-and-web-deployment-projects.aspx