# how to add publish and deployment in a new project window

Tags: c#, setup-deployment

I wish you to be able to help me with this small issue :) please look at below pictures. I don't have publish and deployment in the new project (Visual Studio 2012). how to solve this problem? any idea? i will appreciate your advice!! I need to create a installer setup for my WPF application.

**Publish and deployment image:**

[image: publish and deployment image]

**My problem here:** 
[image: my problem here]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Will Web Deployment Projects still be available in Visual Studio 2012?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11229582/will-web-deployment-projects-still-be-available-in-visual-studio-2012)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft removed the support for setup applications in Visual Studio 2012 (yeah I know it sucks !)

You can use Visual Studio 2010 to create your setup project, [ClickOnce Deployment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) or a third-party setup program like [Inno Setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php).

Comment: I am just using the third-party setup (Inno Setup) as you advised. It worked like a bomb. Thanks very very much :))))

Answer (score 0):

vdproj Setup Project support has been removed in VS2012.

Consider WiX as alternative.

WiX also compiles without installing VS 2012 Professional, although you cannot open WiX project in VS 2012 Express.